# RedisTemplate - required a bean of type `'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate'` that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

@Autowired
public CustomerAuthorizationRepositoryImpl(
        ProtoBufConvertor protoBuffConvertor, RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
    this.protoBuffConvertor = protoBuffConvertor;
    this.redisTemplate= redisTemplate;
  }
```

This is code is working fine, but when we  publish this jar to other application (I mean I create jar of this application) and while deploying or running server with this JAR it is giving me below error - 
Parameter 1 of constructor in `com.customer.repository.CustomerAuthorizationRepositoryImpl` required a bean of type `'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate'` that could not be found.
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate'` in your configuration.

Can anyone help me? How to auto wire properly of RedisTemplate here  so that after publishing this Jar, we were able to get  RedisTemplate instance?

Comment: I have declared this variable on class level like -                          
     @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

Comment: Where does the bean come from? Where is it defined?

Comment: I am pretty sure autowiring your redisTemplate by field AND constructor is redundant. Try removing redisTemplate from your constructor.

Comment: @Autowired private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate; <- this should be fine by itself

Comment: Here only we have declared in repository , and below in the class we have used a database query  redisTemplate.opsForHash().get() , and it isable to fetch the data

Comment: @Solace - when i am tried to remove Redistemplate  from constructor , it is getting same error while Mocking this redisTemplate  in Junit Mock class

Comment: Any update on this? I am getting same error.